# Adding auto number prefix to all files under the directory

Tags: windows, batch-file

Hi how can I add a prefix for all the files (also in subfolder) in the directory using a .bat script?

**Example:**

> Input

`fileNameABC, fileNameDEF, fileNameHIJ...`

> Output

`001-fileNameABC, 002-fileNameDEF, 003-fileNameHIJ.....`

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You should try to write a batch script to accomplish it yourself first..
When you get stuck, then post your script here to seek for help.

Answer (score 0):

Note that this script has a few limitations such as only being designed to number from 001 to 999 (You have to do modifications in several places to extend the range), and a limitation in the way it detects whether a prefix has already been added. But this should get you started...

```
@ECHO OFF
IF %1.==. ECHO Source path not provided & PAUSE & EXIT/B
IF NOT EXIST %1 ECHO Source directory does not exist & PAUSE  & EXIT/B
SETLOCAL
REM This script only supports numerical prefixes in the range 001 to 999
SET P=1000
FOR /R %1 %%I IN (.) DO CALL:0 "%%I"
PAUSE
EXIT/B
:0
REM Uncomment below to restart numbering from 1 for each subfolder
::SET P=1000
FOR %%I IN (%1\*) DO CALL:1 "%%I" || EXIT/B
EXIT/B
:1
IF %P%==1999 ECHO Overflow: Too many files found (More than 999) & EXIT/B 1
REM Additional test to see if prefix may have been added already. This test is not very accurate
SET T=%~N1
CALL:2 %T:~0,1% || CALL:2 %T:~1,1% || CALL:2 %T:~2,1% || IF %T:~3,1%==- EXIT/B 0
REM END: Additional test
SET/A P=P+1
REN %1 "%P:~1%-%~NX1"
EXIT/B 0
:2
REM Make ERRORLEVEL 0, else 1 if %1 is digit
CD.
FOR /L %%I IN (0,1,9) DO IF %1==%%I EXIT/B 1
```